# Php can write a file but can't unlink it, on windows, is it possible?

Tags: php, file-permissions

I've got the following function which i'm using to check if a directory is writable or not.

```
/**
 * check if the path is writable. if the path is a folder it creates a test file.
 *
 * @param string $path
 * @return boolean
 */
public static function is_writable( $path ) {
    //will work in despite of Windows ACLs bug
    //NOTE: use a trailing slash for folders!!!
    //see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27609
    //see http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30931
    if ( $path{strlen($path)-1} === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ) {// recursively return a temporary file path
        return self::is_writable( $path . uniqid( mt_rand() ) . '.tmp' );
    } else if ( is_dir( $path ) ) {
        return self::is_writable( $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . uniqid( mt_rand() ) . '.tmp' );
    }
    $file_already_exists = file_exists( $path );
    // check tmp file for read/write capabilities
    $f = @fopen( $path, 'a');
    if ( $f === false ) {
        return false;
    }
    if ( ! $file_already_exists ) {
        unlink( $path );
    }
    return true;
}
```

This has always worked fine until recently i always get a warning as `unlink()` has no permission to delete the file. But the temp file is created normally so i can write to the dir.

> Warning: unlink(C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-event-calendar-premium\cache\152006398050813468bb6ec.tmp) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\all-in-one-event-calendar-premium\lib\utility\class-ai1ec-filesystem-utility.php on line 35

How is this possible?I've tried to give 777 to the directory i'm testing and i still get the warning! I'm on Windows 7 with Zend server

Comment: add all permission to your wordpress folder (not in php, but in folder properties), sometimes win7 is messing with permission whene you try to read/write/delete file in Program Files...

Comment: `chmod()` is meaningless on Windows. Instead you need to navigate to the folder in explorer, right click -> properties -> security tab -> find the user Zend server is running as in the list -> make sure it has both `modify` and `write` permissions.

Comment: @DaveRandom i was using powershell and chmod is supported, i'll try this, but it's annoying, because if someone else has this problem ( i'm working on a wordpress plugin ) he will get the warningù

Comment: @DaveRandom in httpd.conf the user and group are set as daemon but i can't see that user in the folder security tab

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Those are *nix settings. Have a look in Control Panel -> Administrative tools -> services, find the Apache service and look at which user it is configured to run under. Often this will be SYSTEM

Comment: @DaveRandom the service is run by the local system account and SYSTEM has both modify and write permission

Comment: I suspect UAC is sticking it's nose in where it doesn't belong here. I recommend you adjust your Apache config so that document root resides outside Program Files, and I suspect the problem will go away. This is also generally better practice IMHO.

Comment: @DaveRandom you know a really strange thing?I switched back to another branche and it's not doing this. This is related to PHP. The only difference between the two version it's that here the method is static

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Try adding an `fclose()`, I just noticed you left the file pointer open, maybe that's the cause? Also consider using [`touch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) if all you want to do is determine whether you are able to create the file.

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes i noticed too and that was the cause! Add it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an `fclose()` call, you left the file pointer open after creating the file.

Also consider using [`touch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) if all you want to do is determine whether you are able to create the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your file does not exist when you try unlink. Look here:

```
if ( ! $file_already_exists ) { //TRUE if file does not exist.
    unlink( $path );
}
```

It work when file_exist is FALSE

Comment: This look remarkably like a copy/paste of a previous answer and is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files (x86) is a protected system directory. Try dragging files there with explorer - you'll need to get the necessary rights by nodding off a UAC prompt.

If you want a PHP script to write or delete in this part of the file system, you'll need to run it from an administrative prompt (open the start menu, type "cmd" into the search box, right-click on the cmd command and select "run as administrator").

From that prompt, invoke your PHP script, and it will have all the rights to write to that folder or delete things, and generally wreak havoc on your system wherever the script sees fit ;)

As others have mentioned, chmod() is meaningless in Windows and won't do anything. That's a *nix thing only.

Answer (score -1):

Normally c:\ of windows 7 needs admin writes to add/delete any file.Either give apache uaser admin writes/give htdocs folder 777 permission/move apache docrot outside c:\